# How to play sound from resources using windows media player?

Tags: vb.net, audio, resources, filepath, wmp

I am making a game, so at one point I need to play two sounds at once, so I played the first one using the "My.Computer.Audio.Play()" Method to load from resources.

As for the second, I used Windows Media Player to load the second sound In A SPECIFIC FOLDER, now I know it is possible to extract files to a folder and program it to play from there to avoid trouble, but I don't want them to be extracted.

So I'm trying to get the file path from resources and put it in WMP's URL, but couldn't get any result after searching the internet.

Am I missing something?

And if you know any better alternative, make sure it can:

1- Replay sound (coding with timer is ok),
 2- Change Sound Position

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [MediaPlayer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in code or [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in XAML for playing audio files in a WPF application. Check out the article [WPF Media Player In VB.NET](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/wpf-media-player-in-vb.net) for code samples.